# Trying to use SWT results in many errors

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, swt

As detailed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57574449/9157032) I'm currently trying to find an accessible Java GUI creation library. Because, no, `javax.swing` does not seem to be accessible, but SWT likely is (after all, Eclipse is written in SWT and it's accessible).

The Eclipse Foundation [advises](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/eclipse.php) to include SWT as a dependency into your project. So I downloaded the SWT, unzipped it and imported it into Eclipse as a project. I did not unpack the .jar files, nor did I unzip the src.zip.

Then I created this class:

```
package swt_tests;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
  }
}
```

Two errors popped up: Display cannot get resolved to a type. No surprise. So:
Menu - project - properties - Java build path - tab Projects - class path - add - org.eclipse.SWT - OK - Apply and close.
But the errors did not disappear.
Menu - run - run as... - Java application
led to a warning: Errors in required project(s): org.eclipse.SWT

**Oh?**

I then unzipped src.zip in the original download. Removed SWT from the dependencies. Deleted the SWT project. Imported the SWT project again, this time with src unzipped. Repeat above procedure, and...

860 errors in the Problems view. **WHEW!**

I also tried unpacking the jar file swt.jar, but unsurprisingly that didn't help either.

My Eclipse version is 4.12, downloaded the SWT for that build, too. Java version 11.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? In the *Java Build Path* properties page, on which tab are you adding the SWT jar file?

Comment: Will add this in the question, give me a second.

Comment: @Andy Thomas added this information to the question - tab Projects, Eclipse 4.12 and matching SWT

Comment: In the code snippets the import statement for `Display` is missing. Did you include the SWT dependency directly via the _Java Build Path_ or as advised via the imported project?

Comment: Imported project first as advised, then included that via build path (see the link above). I took the code snippet from one of the snippets (the Hello World snippet), and there is no import statement, either.

Comment: @Howlger if I need an import statement I'd be grateful if you could tell me what the import statement is.

Comment: The last image in that 'advises' link shows the import - `import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*`. You should only need to do what is described in that link.

Comment: @greg-449 thank you very much! As I am blind, I always ignore images as "not useful".

Comment: @TimB - I'd add the jar on the *Libraries* tab of *Java Build Path*.

Comment: Using Ctrl+Shift+O (Organize Imports) may be helpful in Eclipse. It should add the necessary import statement, or prompt if more than one is relevant (for example, if there were two different classes named `Display` on the classpath).

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot, I'll probably use this a lot...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to write an import directive - `import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;` in this case. This directive is missing in the snippets, but is visible in an image in the second link in my question. As I am blind, I didn't notice this.

So, just unzipping the swt download, not the src.zip, and using above import directive solved my problem.

**Edit**: Now the import directive is in the snippets, too. Or maybe I was more blind than usual...